# Error message "iPod is disabled. Try again in 22,236,924 minutes."

Tags: ios, ipod-touch

I think my son was trying to guess the passcode! What do I do?

I can't wait 42 years!

[image]

Comment: Do you already tried to restore it from iTunes backup?

Comment: Wonder how they come up with the number 22,236,924.

Comment: I wonder how man times it took to get to 22,236,924 minutes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No harm done, that is if you have a backup on iTunes.
The [Apple Support pages](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1212) tell you can reset the block by restoring it within iTunes.

> If you cannot remember the passcode, you will need to restore your
>   device using the computer with which you last synced it. This allows
>   you to **reset your passcode** and **resync the data from the device** (or
>   restore from a backup). If you restore on a different computer that
>   was never synced with the device, you will be able to unlock the
>   device for use and remove the passcode, but your data will not be
>   present. Refer to Updating and restoring iPhone, iPad and iPod touch
>   software.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I plugged my iPod Touch to my work computer to charge it. I unplugged it and hooked it up to my personal laptop (the computer with the iTunes account that it is synced to) and it let me put in my password to unlock it! :)